# IOS 8 Objective c UIBarButtonItem action doesnt work

Tags: objective-c, ios8, phonegap-plugins

Im using UIBarButtonItem action and it works on ios 7 and not on ios 8 
In ios 7 after clicking on the button the method cancelButtonPressed (which defined in action) is running but in ios8 nothing happend the cancelButtonPressed method  doesnt called.

```
 id cancelButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                       initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel
                       target:self
                       action:@selector(cancelButtonPressed:)
                       ];
```

Im using it in barcode scanner plugin, it is open the camera and in that screen i have the cancel button:

```
- (UIView*)buildOverlayView {

    if ( nil != self.alternateXib )
    {
        return [self buildOverlayViewFromXib];
    }
    CGRect bounds = self.view.bounds;
    bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, bounds.size.width, bounds.size.height);

    UIView* overlayView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:bounds] autorelease];
    overlayView.autoresizesSubviews = YES;
    overlayView.autoresizingMask    = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
    overlayView.opaque              = NO;

    UIToolbar* toolbar = [[[UIToolbar alloc] init] autorelease];
    toolbar.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin;




    id cancelButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                       initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel
                       target:self
                       action:@selector(cancelButtonPressed:)
                       ];
    //self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem=cancelButton;


    id flexSpace = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] autorelease]
                    initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace
                    target:nil
                    action:nil
                    ];

#if USE_SHUTTER
    id shutterButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                        initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCamera
                        target:(id)self
                        action:@selector(shutterButtonPressed)
                        ];

    toolbar.items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:flexSpace,cancelButton,flexSpace,shutterButton,nil];
#else
    toolbar.items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:flexSpace,cancelButton,flexSpace,nil];
#endif
    bounds = overlayView.bounds;

    [toolbar sizeToFit];
    CGFloat toolbarHeight  = [toolbar frame].size.height;
    CGFloat rootViewHeight = CGRectGetHeight(bounds);
    CGFloat rootViewWidth  = CGRectGetWidth(bounds);
    CGRect  rectArea       = CGRectMake(0, rootViewHeight - toolbarHeight, rootViewWidth, toolbarHeight);
    [toolbar setFrame:rectArea];

    [overlayView addSubview: toolbar];

    UIImage* reticleImage = [self buildReticleImage];
    UIView* reticleView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: reticleImage] autorelease];
    CGFloat minAxis = MIN(rootViewHeight, rootViewWidth);

    rectArea = CGRectMake(
                          0.5 * (rootViewWidth  - minAxis),
                          0.5 * (rootViewHeight - minAxis),
                          minAxis,
                          minAxis
                          );

    [reticleView setFrame:rectArea];

    reticleView.opaque           = NO;
    reticleView.contentMode      = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
    reticleView.autoresizingMask = 0
    | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin
    | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin
    | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin
    | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin
    ;

    [overlayView addSubview: reticleView];

    return overlayView;
}
```

what is the alternative way for using it on ios8?

Comment: are you still not using `ARC` in the third millennium?

Comment: 1. Enable ARC. 2. Use modern Objective-C syntax. 3. See 1.

Comment: Is the shutter button working? What happens if you just add the cancel button and nothing else?

Comment: Im using barcode scanner plugin https://github.com/wildabeast/BarcodeScanner and Arc is disabled, i didnt find any barcode scanner for ios that using ARC. Do you think the problem related to the ARC?

Answer (score 0):

```
remove autorelease and initialize bar button like that

 id cancelButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                   initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel
                   target:self
                   action:@selector(cancelButtonPressed:)
                   ];
 self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem=cancelButton;
```

Comment: can you please share more code and where you are initialising that bar button.bcoz in my case it is working

Comment: i edited my question, when i use your code the cancel button method get fired after 2 minutes not immediately

Comment: i did not get anything useful in this so that i can rectify which thing is making problem in your code

Comment: Im using barcode scanner plugin https://github.com/wildabeast/BarcodeScanner and Arc is disabled, i didnt find any barcode scanner for ios that using ARC.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to make a global variable in class defination or a property for cancelButton instead of using local variable. I guess arc is removing cancelButton from memory.